# Why are C++ iostreams always left-hand assigned?

Tags: c++, iostream

I am learning C++ and have never dealt with streams. I would have expected the notation to be:

```
std::cout << "foo";
char foo << std::cin;
```

I'm sure there's a good reason it is `std::cin >> foo`. What is it?

Comment: Paste this code `char& operator<<(char& dst, std::istream& src) { src >> dst; return dst; }` into yours and play around with `char a; a << std::cin;` a little bit. Oh you might want to try shifting bits in `a`.

Comment: A handy way to remember the difference is that the operator points in the direction of the flow of data. :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It has to do with the associativity of the << and >>  operators.

They were originally only for bit shifting where they are left associative. The operator associativity remains the same when overloaded (otherwise, the code would be impossible to parse):

If you did

```
 int a, b ;
 a << b << cin
```

you'd get

```
(a << b) << cin
```

A bit shift and and input

This is why the standard library does it the way it does.

Comment: The meta-point to make here is that streams are part of the library, not the base language, so the language doesn't have support for a unique operator with syntax fully matching the semantics.  `<<` is actually literally an overload of the bit-shift operator, not just a language feature used in two different ways.

Answer (score 13):

`a << b` and `a >> b` are just shorthands for:

```
operator<<(a,b)
```

and

```
operator>>(a,b)
```

(or the member-function equivalents).

That is, they are just calls to particular functions. It just so happens that the C++ standard library overloads `operator<<` to perform output streaming to `ostream`s, and `operator>>` to perform input streaming from `istream`s.

These functions are only overloaded to have the stream on the left.

There are two reasons for this decision. The first is notational simplicity (that is, since there is only one way of ordering the operands, there is less ambiguity about the meaning of any particular code, and there is less need to implement huge numbers of different overloads when extending the standard library to support an additional class). The second is that `<<` and `>>` are left associative, and so:

```
int a, b;
a << b << cin;
```

would become:

```
(a << b) << cin;
```

while:

```
int a, b;
cin >> b >> a;
```

correctly becomes:

```
(cin >> b) >> a;
```

Answer (score 3):

It's so you'll be forced to put the console on the left the way god intended! :)

It actually has to do with something called operator overloading. If you're just learning C++ you probably haven't covered that yet so file what I'm about to say under "stuff I'll get later".

C++ lives on top of C. In C `<<` and `>>` are just bit shift operators. In c++ it can be more. `std:cout << foo` is NOT C, it's C++. The reason it's C++ is because the `std::cout` object overloads the `<<` operator to mean something other than bit shifting.

In other words, `<<` only means send `foo` to `cout`, because `cout` said that's what it means. `<<` is, in effect, a function on the class `cout`.

It's almost as if you said `std::cout->sendThatToMe(foo)`.

In this whole affair `foo` is just a hapless parameter along for the ride that has no say over what `<<` means. THAT is why you can't do it the other way. If you did it would be as if you were saying this:

```
foo->sendMeToThat( std::cout).
```

Which can be made to work IF you add that function (well the `>>` operator really) to every stinking object you might ever want to send to the console. Oh and good luck pulling it off with primitives.

So while I think there are very good style reasons to want to keep the console stuff on the left there actually is a technical reason it has to be that way. It's because operators being overloaded are already left associative. They have been since they were used to shift bits in the old C days. Overloading them doesn't offer a chance to change their associativity.

Answer (score 0):

Thats just the way they are supposed to work. I think this was done to clearly differentiate input operations ( >> ) from output operations ( << ).
If you overload the `<<` operator in this fancy way (As Captain Obvious suggested in comments):

```
template<typename T>
std::istream& operator<<( T& data , std::istream& is )
{
    is >> data;
    return *this;
}
```

It will be less clear if the operaton was input or output (With `std::cin std::cout` its easy, but thing about two streams named `file1` and `file2`, one for reading and one for writting):

```
a << std::cin;
std::cout << a;

a << file;
file << a;
```